# How to create unlimited sub category in drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

Would you please guide me on how to create unlimited category and sub category in a drop down list using php and mysql?

I was the sub category to have --- in front of them. For example, the first sub category --- and the second level ----- and so on:
I want to achieve some thing like this:-

```
<select name="category">
<option value="1">Root</option>
<option value="3">- Sub </option>
<option value="4">- - Sub</option>
<option value="5">Root</option>
<option value="6">- Sub </option>
<option value="7">- - Sub</option>
</select>
```

Here is the code I got so far

```
function get_category($parentID = 0){
  global $mysqli;
  $html = '';
  // Prepare the query
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT CategoryID, Title
                            FROM category
                            WHERE ParentID =?");
  // Bind param
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $parentID);

  // Execute the query
  $stmt->execute();

  // Store the result
  $stmt->store_result();

  // Bind the result
  $stmt->bind_result($categoryID, $title);
  while($stmt->fetch()){
    $html .= "<option value=\"$categoryID\">$title</option>";

    $child = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT CategoryID
                               FROM category
                               WHERE ParentID =?");

    // Execute the query
    $child->bind_param('i', $categoryID);
    $child->execute();

    // Store the result
    $child->store_result();

    // Bind the result
    $has_child = NULL;
    $has_child = $child->num_rows;
    if($has_child){
      $html .= get_category($categoryID); 
    }
  }

  return $html;
}
echo '<select name="category">';
print(get_category());
echo '</select>';
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I do not think stackoverflow is made up for getting development work done for free. I guess people would be more willing to answer if you ask concrete questions:

Comment: I do not think stackoverflow is made up for getting development work done for free. I guess people would be more willing to answer if you ask concrete questions. Anyway here are some starting points: 1. I think mysqli is deprecated. 2. mysql does not support tree traversal out of the box (just google: mysql connect by prior OR mysql tree traversal to get some ideas how to work around) 3. if you setup any tree traversal work around you could make it reusable by separating the html enrichment into another function

Comment: mysqli is not deprecated... mysql is deprecated... the code I provided is a functional code and it out put the categories and subcategories.. what I need is to add --- for the sub categories since we can't use indentation in the drop down list..

Comment: @Quicker that's mysql_* library not MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: See my updated link @user2589904

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/1800/). Its in mysql format

Check this also

```
<?php
// Get listing of base categories
$sql="SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM cat_table where cat_parent='0' ORDER BY cat_name asc";
$basecat = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql);
print"<select name=\"category\">";
while($cat_list=mysql_fetch_array($basecat)){
if ($cat_list[0]==$cur_cat){$test= ' selected';}else{$test='';}
print '<option value="'.$cat_list[0].'"'.$test.'>'.$cat_list[1].'</option>';
sub_cat($cat_list[0]);// this calls the function for sub cats
}
print'</select>';
// ***********************************************************************
// Sub-Category Function
function sub_cat($cat_num){
$subcat = mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM cat_table where cat_parent='$cat_num' ORDER BY cat_name asc");
while($sub_cat_list = mysql_fetch_array($subcat)){
if ($sub_cat_list[0]==$cur_cat){$test=' selected';}else{$test='';}
print '<option value="'.$sub_cat_list[0].'"'.$test.'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$sub_cat_list[1].'</option>';
}
}
// ***********
```

Result like this format

```
<select name="category">
<option value="4">Advertising</option>
<option value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Newspaper</option>
<option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Radio</option>
<option value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Television</option>
<option value="2">Autos</option>
<option value="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevy</option>
<option value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dodge</option>
<option value="6">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ford</option>
<option value="3">Marketing</option>
</select>
```

Updated [Link](http://www.mamunurrashid.info/main/php/categories-and-subcategories-in-select-list.html)

Comment: I will test it later.. I am busy doing something now.. I will let you know when I test it.. if it works for me, I will accept your answer so other people can benefit from it